# How to use different font sizes on 480x800 and 1280x760 screen?

Tags: android, layout, font-size

I have read [Different font sizes for different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713812/different-font-sizes-for-different-screen-sizes), but I found that is not working well for me.

I created a `values-hdpi` to define styles, but I found both `480x800` and `1280x760` use it -- the screen size is so different!

Is there any way to let `480x800` screen use one font size and `1280x760` use another one?

Comment: Use the sp unit. (which is the same as dp, but for fonts) This will ensure that the size is scales based on dots-per-inch (dpi).

Comment: no. SP is the same as DP, but it gets scaled up or down if the user chooses larger / smaller fonts at the system level, in their preferences: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Create screen-specific [dimensions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) files, like this,

```
values-sw720dp/dimens.xml
values-sw600dp/dimens.xml
values/dimens.xml
```

The first is for 10" tablets, the second is for 7" tablet, and the last is for phones. If that doesn't give you the gradations you want, read [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to find out other ways of targeting different screens.

In those files, define a dimension,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen
        name="my_size">40sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

adjust the dimension value in each of the dimens.xml files to your liking.

Now in your layout,

```
<TextView ...
  android:textSize="@dimen/my_size"/>
```